# How can I add parameters when creating a TableSection in C#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have XAML code that adds a TableSection footer:

```
<TableSection Title="Cards1" local:Ex.FooterText="Sample description">
```

Can someone tell me how I can do the same for when I create this in C#. I tried this but it doesn't work at all so I assume there is a different way to do this:

```
var newSection = new TableSection("Cards1") {
    local:Ex.FooterText; "Sample description"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a so-called attached property. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties/#Consuming_an_Attached_Property).

In code, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var newSection = new TableSection("Cards1");
Ex.SetFooterText(newSection, "Sample description");
```

Of course I don't know the exact attached property that you're trying to use, so this is a bit of a guess, but hopefully you can figure it out with this.

Just make sure that you put whatever is in the `xmlns:local` attribute in your XAML is added as a using to your C# class.